# Compare two dataframes to get comparison value in in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, each in the following format with the same index and different values:

```
       Value
Date
01-01    60
01-02    70
01-03   -80
```

I need to compare the two dataframes where values of `df1 < df2` and get only those values for which the comparison stands true with their respective indices in a third dataframe `df_new`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you merge your two data frames based on the index so that you can compare the values between each columns.

Try this:

```
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
  data=[60, 70, -80],
  index=['01-01', '01-02', '01-03'],
  columns=['Value'])

df2 = pandas.DataFrame(
  data=[59, 69, -79],
  index=['01-01', '01-02', '01-03'],
  columns=['Value'])


df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_1', '_2'))

df3['Delta'] = df3['Value_2'] - df3['Value_1']
```

It will return you the following dataframe:

```
       Value_1  Value_2  Delta
01-01       60       59     -1
01-02       70       69     -1
01-03      -80      -79      1
```

Here is the link to the merge method:
[pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)